# Android what is the fastest and most proper way to loop/repeat math forever?

Tags: java, android

I'm starting to program in Android and creating a game that constantly does math and displays a rapidly changing number (basic addition, but with large numbers)

I have worked with `.postDelayed()` while pressing a button, but I feel like this isn't the best or most efficient way of doing this.  I also would like to know what the fastest recommended speed is for something that repeats?

My button acts like this:

```
    buttonAdd.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    myMethod();
                    buttonAdd.postDelayed(myMethodRun, delay);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    buttonAdd.removeCallbacks(myMethodRun);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    Runnable myMethodRun = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myMethod();
            buttonAdd.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    };
```

I was thinking of doing the same thing with just using the root view to make a `postDelayed()`

```
body.postDelayed(runForever, delayTime);

Runnable runForever = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runForever();
            buttonAdd.postDelayed(this, delay);
        }
    };
```

Is `while(true)` a good way of doing this? I don't want to overload everything

Is this the way to do it? or will I be using too much of the UI thread?  Obviously, I'm still a bit new.  **I'd like to repeat a method forever and I'd like to know what the fastest recommended delay time is**

Answer (score 1):

For a game, all that matters is user experience, a major component of which is frame count.  If you maintain a decent frame count, like 30 frames per second, then the user perceives all transitions in the game as smooth. Or smooth enough, if you wish. The game may have an even better feel if you go to higher fps, like 60 frames per second, but the difference is hardly worth the additional power consumption on a mobile device.  (Currently, 60 fps is only done in high end games running on high end hardware, like consoles or Desktop PCs with top of the line graphics cards.)

So, if you shoot for 30 frames per second, then you will only need to render a frame once every 33 milliseconds.  Performing calculations any faster than that is pointless, because it would mean that you would be calculating stuff that you are never going to render, and therefore the user will never see.

So, just set up a timer to fire every 33 milliseconds, do your calculations, render your frame, return to the operating system until the timer fires again.

Comment: Great advice Mike! Thank you!  I'll take a look into the `Timer` class.